# CSS stylesheet works hosted locally, but not remote

Tags: html, css, amazon-s3, browser, localhost

I have a simple, local HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="myclass">Hello World</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and a simple stylesheet:

```
.myclass {
    color: #456123;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I am deploying my stylesheet to an outside cloud hosting service (AWS S3). However, when I swap the URL out, the styles don't work anymore:
`<link href="https://example.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>`

What do I mean by they don't work? The page doesn't display correctly, none of my styles get applied. The page renders as if there was no stylesheet at all.

I've tested all the obvious things, and then some:

- The remote stylesheet is accessible, I downloaded it separately by URL and WGet
- The remote stylesheet is the exact same as local, byte-for-byte (no diff)
- I have disabled cache in my browser
- I have hard refreshed
- Per my browser tools > network tab, the browser loads the stylesheet promptly (~200ms)
- Per my browser tools > sources tab, I can confirm that the entire stylesheet is there, present as a source and readable
- I even wrote a script that I loaded into the body that fetched the CSS stylesheet externally, and using a callback after that, created the myclass div. The styles still didn't apply, even when controlling for latency/race conditions like that.

What could be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! I found a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14807743/2844655), which led me to the answer: when CSS files get uploaded to AWS, they get uploaded as `Content-Type: Binary/Octet-Stream` for some godforsaken reason. (Madness!)

My browser tools didn't raise that as an issue -- I guess browsers are pretty flexible these days -- but it must've still been an issue for HTML rendering.

So the solution is simple: go into AWS S3, click on the file, and change its metadata to hold:`Content-Type: text/css`. Or you can also set that metadata programmatically if you're uploading these files via an AWS CLI or SDK.

As an aside, you should do the same for JS files, which also get uploaded as `binary/octet-stream`. For whatever reason, the browser is still able to execute those fine.